# Flap t/d after r-controlled

Tags: grammar

I' m struggling with flap t/d after r-controlled vowels in words like chortle, startle, mortal, turtle. I thought of dropping the r before the flap but I noticed that when omitted the r-controlle it led me to a mistake. Example, when I would say mortal omitting the r I pronounce Model, and omitted the flap t to then I said Moral.

I am in a beginning level, but now I now where are my weaknesses I can improve. Please suggest me how I can make a progress, what exetcise I could do...

I am looking forword to your help!

Comment: Lots of native Anglophones in UK SE don't really articulate the /r/ and /l/ in words like "chortle" - which ends up being more like "chaw-taw". It doesn't matter much, so long as you're understood.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Some Americans write (and presumably say) _studder_ for _stutter_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I think *on average*, Americans tend to articulate /r/ more than Brits, and I'm pretty sure the two shifts I pointed out above are far more common in Brits. But maybe some Americans do all three, and say "chortle" as "chaw-daw". We'd probably understand without giving it a second thought, though. It doesn't usually take long to "tune" your ear to any consistently-applied difference in pronunciation arising from "regional accent", even when "region" basically amounts to "continent".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - after I moved away from London, I started noticing that Cockney Londoners said 'foo'baw'.

Comment: What are you focusing on when making the transition, the tip of your tongue or what your chin is doing?